# Complex number raised to irrational power

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, irrational-numbers

Why are there infinitely many values if a complex number is raised to an irrational power? I have to prove this, and don't know how. I am thinking Cauchy sequences, but I don't know how to start. Could you you please help? Thanks!

Comment: $z^a=e^{a\log z}$

Answer (score 4):

It's a matter of definition. If $a,b\in\mathbb C$ and $a\neq0$, then $a^b$ is *any* number of the form $\exp(b\log a)$, where $\log a$ is *any* logarithm of $a$. But if $l_a$ is *one* logarithm of $a$, then$$\{\text{logarithms of }a\}=\{l_a+2\pi im\,|\,m\in\mathbb{Z}\}.$$So, if $b$ is irrational and if $m\neq n$, then$$\exp\bigl(b(l_a+2\pi im))\neq\exp\bigl(b(l_a+2\pi in)).$$